# How to eliminate the ajax function of a contact form?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, contact-form

Yes, here is the landing page I bought: http://webuza.com/demo/landing/Advisa/index1.html

I want you to try and register.

The success AND error messages that appear after registering, show up in the same page, with the same URL.

I think that is the ajax function, right?

I want to keep the ajax function for error messages, but I want the SUCCESS message to appear in a whole new page, with a whole new url, something like: contact-thank-you.html.

I already created the html thank you page, but I don't know how to direct people there, after they successfully submit.

Any ideas?

Please, please!

:D

Here is my js code, which is in a document called custom.js:

```
// ********************************
// Request and contact Form
// ********************************
$("#formIndex, #contact").submit(function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        var urlTarget = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : urlTarget,
                dataType : "html",
                data : $(this).serialize(),
                beforeSend : function() {
                    elem.prepend("<div class='loading alert'>" + "<a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>" + "Loading" + "</div>");
                },
                success : function(response) {
                    elem.prepend(response);
                    elem.find(".loading").hide();
                    elem.find("input[type='text'],input[type='email'],textarea").val("");
                }
        });
        return false;
});
```

Here is my php code, which is in a document called contact-form.php:

```
<?php
    $to="company.email";/*Your Email*/
    $subject="Message from the Landing - Contact Form ";

    $date=date("l, F jS, Y");
    $time=date("h:i A");

    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
    $caoch=$_REQUEST['caoch'];
    $file=$_REQUEST['file'];


    $msg="
        Message sent from Landing Contact Form on date  $date, hour: $time.\n
        First Name: $name\n
        Email: $email\n
        Phone: $phone\n
        Caoch: $caoch\n
        File: $file
        ";
    if($email=="") {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
              <a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>
              <strong>Warning!</strong> Please fill all the fields.
          </div>";
    } else {
    mail($to,$subject,$msg,"From:".$email);
    header("class='alert alert-success' Location: contact-thank-you.html");
    exit;

    }


?>
```

Here is the HTML code, of the home page:

```
<form class='reg-now-visible' id='formIndex' action="contact-form.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" role="form">
                                <div class='control-group'>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder='Enter your name' data-required>
                                </div>
                                <div class='control-group'>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" value="" class='insert-attr' placeholder='Enter your mail' data-required>
                                </div>
                                <div class='control-group'>
                                    <input type="text" name="phone" value="" placeholder='Enter your telephone' data-required data-pattern="^[0-9]+$">
                                </div>


                                    <div class="relative">
                                        <select name="caoch" class="styled">
                                            <option value="Select Your Caoch">Select Your Caoch</option>
                                            <option value="Caoch 1" >Caoch 1</option>
                                            <option value="Caoch 2" >Caoch 2</option>
                                            <option value="Caoch 3" >Caoch 3</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="relative">
                                        <select name="file" class="styled">
                                            <option value="Select File">Select File</option>
                                            <option value="File 1">File 1</option>
                                            <option value="File 2">File 2</option>
                                            <option value="File 3">File 3</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                 <button type="submit" value="Register Now" class='btn submit sub-form' name="submit">Register Now</button>
                            </form>

                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your AJAX call to be like this:

```
$('#formIndex, #contact').submit(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  var urlTarget = elem.attr('action');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlTarget,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: elem.serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
      elem.prepend('<div class="loading alert><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a>Loading</div>');
    },
    success: function(response) {
      response = $(response);
      if (response.hasClass('alert-success')) {
        location.href = 'URL TO YOUR CONTACT-THANK YOU PAGE';
      } else {
        elem.prepend(response);
        elem.find('.loading').remove();
        elem.find('input[type="text"], input[type="email"], textarea').val('');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Amelle!! Do I have to erase anything from the ajax call? What do I keep? What do I put below else? Thanks!!!

Comment: @RiversO No you don't have to erase anything, just add those lines in my answer. The `...`s just say "more core here" haha :)

Comment: @Amelle Balane, I put the code, just after the 
success : function(response) paragraph, but the success message still appears on the same page, using ajax, keeping the same url. Here is my landing page: http://crediflash.com.mx/dinerohoy.html

Comment: @RiversO Wait let me edit my answer to show the whole AJAX call.

Comment: @Amelle, I followed your suggestion, but my thank you message keeps appearing on the same page, with the same URL.

Comment: @RiversO hmmm, that probably means that it fails to execute the code inside the `if` block. I mean maybe `response.hasClass('alert-success')` is false. The key here is to make it execute the `if` block. Can you please check what `response.hasClass('alert-success')` is evaluated to? Just log it in the console.

Comment: @Amelle! Try and registering now: http://crediflash.com.mx/dinerohoy.html
It now directs you to a page, but to the incorrect one... even though I never asked it to go there.

Comment: @RiversO Can you tell me what is being logged in the console when you put `console.log(response.hasClass("alert-success"));` after `response = $(response);`? I can't open your site, it's throwing `HTTP ERROR: 504`.

Comment: This is what I put:  response = $(response);
      if (response.hasClass('alert-success')) {
        location.href = 'contact-thank-you.html';

Comment: @RiversO Try using the full URL and not just `contact-thank-you.html`.

Comment: I tried that, @Arnelle, same result. I will edit my question, so you can see what I put in my contact-form.php document, on the "else".

Comment: Finally!! Thanks, @Arnelle!!! I edited your answer a little so that it has the complete solution... thank you, thank you!!! I don't know why others downvoted my question, but thank you for answering, it helped a lot. :D

Comment: @RiversO Cool, glad to help :) Still can't accept your edit though, I don't have enough reputation haha. I'll accept it in time :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should ask to support team where you bought that template now around your problem you should return some JSON and take advantage of that on the jQuery code, for example:

```
$.get('URL').success(function (data) {
    if (data.error) {
        // Show the error message on the same page and prevent the default behavior
    } else {
        // then all was fine so this is your success
        location.href = 'another'; // where another is the page where you want to show your success message
    }
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    if (status == '500') {
        console.log("No server connection");
    }
});
```

Hope this help

Comment: You should read the code and try to understand it then you can change the default function (the one you posted) for my code and try if it helps and works, if you copy/paste my code won't work since it's just an example

Comment: I am super new @ this, I don't understand coding that much yet. D:

Comment: I'm away from my computer, when I come back tomorrow if you don't get the issue solved I'll try to help you with the complete code